# How to restrict object types based on a value in the object?

Tags: javascript, typescript

For now I'm using this type alias:

```
export type Country = {
  name: 'USA' | 'Russia' | 'Bulgaria' | 'Romania' | 'Austria' | 'Great Britain' | 'Italy',
  code: 'us' | 'ru' | 'bg' | 'ro' | 'au' | 'gb' | 'it'
};
```

But it allows to create incorrect objects:

```
{ name: 'USA', code: 'ru'}
```

What is the best way to make a type for this purpose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a discriminated union approach:

```
type Country = {
    name: 'USA',
    code: 'us',
} | {
    name: 'Russia',
    code: 'ru',
} | {
    name: 'Bulgaria',
    code: 'bg',
} | {
    name: 'Romania',
    code: 'ro',
} | {
    name: 'Austria',
    code: 'au',
} | {
    name: 'Great Britain',
    code: 'gb',   
} | {
    name: 'Italy',
    code: 'it',   
};

// works
const myCountry: Country = {
    name: 'USA',
    code: 'us',
};

// does not
const myCountry2: Country = {
    name: 'USA',
    code: 'ru',
};
```

More reading [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions)

You could also use a paramater map, but then you would have to specify the paramater on the interface:

```
type CountryMap = {
    USA: 'us',
    Russia: 'ru',
    Bulgaria: 'bg',
    Romania: 'ro',
    Austria: 'au',
    'Great Britain': 'gb',
    Italy: 'it',
};

interface ICountry<T extends keyof CountryMap> {
    name: T;
    code: CountryMap[T];
}

// works
const myICountry: ICountry<'USA'> = {
    name: 'USA',
    code: 'us'
};

// does not
const myICountry2: ICountry<'USA'> = {
    name: 'USA',
    code: 'ru',
};
```

Working typescript playground for both examples [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=61&ssc=3&pln=36&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gVwHbAE4igXigbwFBSFRICGAthAFxQDkAqgMoCCNANAUQMZwAmVtCAM5s8AXygAfXB0KkK1GgCUhggJYkRRKNz4LUCEeKn4tc-jQBCCADYBzEqnWauvcwCNbhydNPlziuDISJCd2LR1zVDgvYxliPwUmITRQuIiFEgN2Ix8iMwUAcVQIEmAoC0dgElUkZ0J02ls3NiIxbxM8hNoASSrrEDrtVwVVYBbCMQBuPDwAelmoAHc4VABrQTxuJEEyshB4ZDQQagOUdCxc2S76ZkGGmiFDabmFnjgIQWI4YE24bd39ogziAAEwnIFHC4dK7yWiMFhhFy6Wj6J4zUCQWAQ9AAWRIYChcXhCkeiMIykEahIeiycSsdgc6gUHkGASCIWpKOiZKgSR2jk5NEygxoRRKZQqo2qtQUTUGvRI-RGY2yzxqwAgqAAZiRONBuqcjgAeAAqUAgAA8NUgeJ9VhAQHAtVjDrj8QA%20S7xWEm6bhYYu4F4sAAbRNAF1pqIZvMlit1r9-lA9gbsccoKnXSAjTcWJ7sNDveZ4XcAw9hFMY693p8kN9EztkyBM8CwRnDegcyX8178nDbjz7qjVUA)

Answer (score 1):

That isn't good to constuct such types manually. Provide single type definging courtry codes (you already got it) and accompany it with exported funciton of type `CountryCode -> CountryName`. You may want to require some other parametrs that define naming strategy (localization, short/full names, etc.).